# Windows 11 not in grub menu. Do I add the windows partition or the bootloader partition to grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I am trying to get windows 11 on my grub bootloader. I tried putting the windows partition euid into grub(had to do it manually cuz the copy and paste was being strange)
Windows shows up in the grub but will not boot. Do I have to put the windows bootloader's euid into grub as well? Do I put both the windows partition and windows bootloader into grub?

Comment: If grub added it to menu, it saw the boot files in the ESP for UEFI boot. But grub only boots working Windows. Bitlock & fast start up must be off. Directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, with same key you used to boot USB flash drive. If that does not boot, then you need Windows repairs using your Windows repair/recovery flash dirve (you did make one?).

Comment: Yea bitlocker is enabled unfortunately. Is that the problem?

Comment: Also do you know a good Linux iso burner. If I could just reinstall windows 11. I feel like bitlocker is going to make this difficult.windows  is A Fresh install on the hard drive so I don't mind reinstall and turning of bitlocker. Then I would reinstall grub by the Ubuntu USB?

Comment: You should not need to reinstall Windows to turn bitlocker off. Its just a setting in Windows. Best to create any Windows installers from Windows. Issue is that for UEFI boot you need FAT32. And FAT32 has a max file size of 4GB. But Windows makes its .wim file over 4GB. The Windows installer splits the .wim to make it work. A few newer Linux tools may work.